# Raspberry Pi GPIO Output Inversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I have just started playing around with a Raspberry Pi. I have been trying out some initial sensor testing and am confused if I am not getting an intuition, or if I am doing something wrong. Basically, the power outputs seem to be inverted.

I am using `RPi.GPIO` and this example is just for getting an RGB light working. My initial setup is:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import random

pins = {'red': 11, 'green': 12, 'blue': 13}

def setup():
    global pwmRed,pwmGreen,pwmBlue  
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)                      # Physical GPIO Numbering
    GPIO.setup(list(pins.values()), GPIO.OUT)     # RGB LED pins in OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.output(list(pins.values()), GPIO.HIGH)   # RGB LED pins output set to HIGH
    pwmRed = GPIO.PWM(pins.get('red'), 2000)      # set PWM Frequence to 2kHz
    pwmGreen = GPIO.PWM(pins.get('green'), 2000)  # set PWM Frequence to 2kHz
    pwmBlue = GPIO.PWM(pins.get('blue'), 2000)    # set PWM Frequence to 2kHz

    pwmRed.start(0)                               # Duty Cycle set to 0 <--- This should be off
    pwmGreen.start(0)
    pwmBlue.start(0)
```

I thought this means all three lights should be off to start with. However, when run, the light comes on white (all three at 100% Duty Cycle).

Furthermore, if I use:

```py
def manual_colour():
    rgb = input("Values (comma separated): ")
    return [int(v) for v in rgb.split(',')]
```

to manually set the rgb colour then `[0, 100, 100]` will make the light red.

I thought that a Duty Cycle of 100 would have meant that the light would be on full power and that 0 would be off. Am I doing something wrong, or is my intuition the wrong way around?

Comment: Try to remove this line `GPIO.output(list(pins.values()), GPIO.HIGH)   # RGB LED pins output set to HIGH`.

Comment: I have just tried that but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Have a look for `piscope`. It should let you monitor what the state of the GPIO pins is so you can see whether the pins are pulsing as you expect.

Comment: Pls share your circuit diagram

Comment: The pasted code looks fine, so it is hard to help. My generic advice is: start with a known-to-work code sample and move from there. This looks like a good starting point: https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/